# How web3 protocols know which UTXOs should be consumed

Tags: utxo

I'm trying to get the history interaction of a wallet on Levvy Fi via Cardano db sync. But I find it difficult to understand how Levvy Fi generates a wallet with their scripts and how they know which UTXOs could be consume from their side.

Could anyone explain to me how protocols know which UTXOs should be consumed and which UTXOs they have the right to consume?

For instance, this transaction has 2 UTXOs that have a script generated by Levvy.Fi

https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/ef276d849fffe232c999cd802a4197eb3bd5c9ced90f1ec92b1c5446332553b5?tab=utxo

But How Levvy.Fi knows that they have the right to consume these 2 UTXOs. Assuming that in the wallet "addr1zy6r74xk4haj26c7jpq6w25t2xt8qzr9wr2kz805n8re02nsxfk6rvced60w4h629n75rs2wsfpyg5yjuxjc3rvd0adqh0f057" have many UTXOs available.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Levvy.Fi does, but anyone knows which UTXO they can spend by looking at UTXO's address -- they can spend it when:

- it's a hash of a key (wallet) they control, or
- if it's a hash of a script they know the source for and can provide a redeemer for

Which specific UTXOs to spend is up to the spender (application, wallet) to choose arbitrarily.